# When creating a new WC_Order, what's the best way to calculate shipping costs

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm creating a ReSTFUL way to initiate an order via WooCommerce, my code is as follows

```
function submitOrder($token, $productIDs, $shipping)
    {

        $order = wc_create_order();
        $product_item_id = $order->add_product( wc_get_product( $productIDs[0]['productID'] ));
        
        //wc_add_order_item_meta($product_item_id,"meta_key","meta_values");
        $addressShipping = array(
               'first_name' => $shipping['first_name'],
               'last_name'  => $shipping['last_name'],
               'email'      => $shipping['email'],
               'phone'      => $shipping['phone'],
               'address_1'  => $shipping['address']['street'],
               'city'       => $shipping['address']['city'],
               'state'      => $shipping['address']['state'],
               'postcode'   => $shipping['address']['postcode'],
               'country'    => 'AU');
        
        $order->set_address( $addressShipping, 'shipping' );            
        $order->set_address( $addressShipping, 'billing' );
```

I've been reading the [WooCommerce Docs](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/class-WC_Shipping.html) and I have a rough understanding on how to retrieve a `WC_Shipping` class.

However, to go through the Shipping Zones, work out if the minimum order has been reached, etc, seems tedious.
Is there a method that already works out the best shipping Method (based on the content of the `WC_Order`) then returns a `WC_Shipping` class to attach to the `WC_Order`?

I noticed that there is a `calculate_shipping()` method, which takes on a `package` Array. I couldn't find anything on this Array and what data is needed. Would this do the job?